# Meter: embedding templates in Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Using Bootstrap and Meteor / Blaze, I am trying to dynamically control the size of a template using a template helper. I'd like to have a button to switch between **col-md-4** and **col-md-12**. The hard-coded column sizing looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
   {{#each articles}}
      <div class="col-md-4">
         {{> article this}}
      </div>
   {{/each}}
 </div>
```

I have a template helper that returns the **div** and found I needed a closing helper call, or Meteor could complain about an unbalanced **<\div>**. This seems a bit hacky.

```
Template.articles.helpers({
  format: function() {
      return '<div class="col-md-4">';
      // return '<div class="col-md-12">';
  },
  end_format: function() {
      return '</div>'
  }
});
```

The markup is:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
      {{#each articles}}
          {{{format}}}
              {{> article this}}
          {{{end_format}}}
      {{/each}}
   </div>
</div>
```

But the **div** tags are returned closed and empty, with the markup I'd like enclosed underneath, as can be seen in this screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return HTML from template helpers, there is usually a better way.

Why don't you return a dynamic class name from a template helper ?

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    {{#each articles}}
      <div class="{{columnSize}}">
        {{> article this}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-toggle-column-size">Toggle column size</button>
</div>
```

ES2015

```
Template.articles.onCreated(function(){
  this.largeColumns = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.articles.helpers({
  columnSize(){
    const largeColumns = Template.instance().largeColumns.get();
    return largeColumns ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-4';
  }
});

Template.articles.events({
  'click .js-toggle-column-size'(event, template){
    const largeColumns = template.largeColumns.get();
    template.largeColumns.set(!largeColumns);
  }
});
```